# How to print list elements without spaces?

Tags: python, json

```
import json

data = ['A + G', 'B + F', 'C + E', 'D + D']
print(json.dumps(data, indent=0))
```

The above code displays the output:

```
[
"A + G",
"B + F",
"C + E",
"D + D"
]
```

But I want it to be:

```
["A + G", 
 "B + F", 
 "C + E", 
 "D + D"]
```

I have tried changing the indent of the Json, but that doesn't work. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Another option: `print('[' + ',\n '.join(map(json.dumps, data)) + ']')`

Answer (score 1):

If you are just using `json` for the print output, you can skip it and get the output you want with something like:

```
data = ['A + G', 'B + F', 'C + E', 'D + D']

for i, d in enumerate(data):
    if (i == 0):
        print('["{}"'.format(d))
    elif (i == len(data) - 1):
        print(' "{}"]'.format(d))
    else:
        print(' "{}"'.format(d))

# OUTPUT
# ["A + G"
#  "B + F"
#  "C + E"
#  "D + D"]
```

Answer (score 1):

`print('['+json.dumps(data, indent=1)[3:-2]+']')` is really ugly, but works

Answer (score 0):

Another shorter, but hackier way: (if you know you'll always have '[\n' and '\n]' at the start and end) strip those chars and just put '[' and ']'

```
import json

data = ['A + G', 'B + F', 'C + E', 'D + D']
raw = json.dumps(data, indent=0)

new = raw[2:-2]
print('['+new+']')
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty:

```
import json

def cut_ends(string):
    string = string.replace('\n]',']')
    string = string.replace('[\n','[')
    return string

data = ['A + G', 'B + F', 'C + E', 'D + D']

print(cut_ends(json.dumps(data, indent=0)))
```